# Javascript add animate

Tags: javascript, php, animation

I have a simple script to show and replace custom div

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function switchVisible() {
        if (document.getElementById('chat-opened')) {

            if (document.getElementById('chat-opened').style.display == 'none') {
                document.getElementById('chat-opened').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('chatbox').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('chat-opened').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('chatbox').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I wanna to add some animation, like scrolling or something else. Any help? Thanks for replies guys i'm really new on javascript!

Comment: Don't change the style - add classes and css transitions.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Transitions can be an amazing option to add animation effects to elements.

In your CSS use the ids of chatbox and chat-opened to give a fading effect when you set its display to none and similarly when you set its display to be block. This would give you a smooth fading effect when your elements disappear and appear back again.

For more transition effects check out Mozilla's guide for CSS Transitions

[MDN CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments by Philipp transition cannot be applied to display property.

You could instead use the visibility property and apply the transition effect to it.

But keep in mind the visibility property only "hides" your element. It still occupies the space it did.

Comment: Sadly, there's no transition between `display:block` and `none`

Comment: You're right @Philipp transition cannot be applied to display but it could be to visibility.

Comment: But visibility is also a hard jump from visible to invisible - you maybe want to use opacity, height oder any other property, which handles floating point values